# YouTube comments box not showing

Tags: youtube, comments

I opening in https://www.youtube.com in Chrome. But I cannot comment on any video. YouTube comments box itself is missing.

Comments are not disabled in those videos am trying to comments. I can see others comments. I have **signed in** already.

I can comment through my **mobile** in YouTube **application**. Whats wrong any ideas?

Here is one sample.

[image]

If am not wrong the comments box should appear after the video summary. Clearly it is missing. From below picture you can see I have **"signed in"** also

[image]

Comment: Just happened to me today too. Using Chrome BTW. Firefox is okay. But earlier today it was fine on Chrome. Then I signed out, then back in, then gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have some extensions installed. Even if the extension is disabled for YouTube, they can still cause issues (since YouTube is using a zoo of domains to host different kinds of functions).

That said, you are using the new design. The new design is currently in experimental A/B-testing phase, so your version indeed may be broken. I recommend sending feedback at the bottom of the sidebar so the developers know about it.

Answer (score -1):

Comment box appears just below the video.Check your Temporarily disable all plugins, extensions, and add-ons in your browser.